# detached entity passed to persist spting boot with command save

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am testing my repository. In one of the tests I have to add a skill collection which consists of “skill-group” and “skill-detail”. I tested by making new objects of the latest, but when I try to test using an existing value in those 2 tables, I get “detached entity passed to persist” error.

I read other problems, but I couldn't really find a prober answer to my problem.

the error message is the dollowing:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached
> entity passed to persist:
> com.example.demo.skill_related.skill_group.SkillGroup; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
> passed to persist:
> com.example.demo.skill_related.skill_group.SkillGroup

The detail model:

```
public class SkillGroup {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "skillGroups_sequence",
        sequenceName = "skillGroups_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "skillGroups_sequence")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "TEXT", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "type", columnDefinition = "CHAR(2)")
private char type;
}
```

The detail model:

```
public class SkillDetail {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "skillDetail_sequence",
        sequenceName = "skillDetail_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "skillDetail_sequence")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "TEXT",  unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;
}
```

The collection model:

```
public class SkillCollection {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "skillCol_sequence",
        sequenceName = "skillCol_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "skillCol_sequence")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "skill_group", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)
private SkillGroup skillGroups;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "skill_detail", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)
private SkillDetail skillDetails;
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
    @Test
public void makeNewSkills() {

//        SkillGroup skillGroup = SkillGroup.builder()
//                .name("Gebruikersinteractie")
//                .type('B')
//                .build();

    SkillGroup skillGroup = skillGroupRepo.findSkillGroupByName("Gebruikersinteractie");

    SkillDetail skillDetail = SkillDetail.builder()
            .name("Advisceren")
            .build();

    SkillCollection skillCollection = SkillCollection.builder()
            .skillGroups(skillGroup)
            .skillDetails(skillDetail)
            .build();

    skillCollectionRepo.save(skillCollection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot persist the SkillCollection object with SkillDetail and SkillGroup object attributes without adding the id attribute when creating the SkillDetail and SkillGroup objects.

Because you're using findSkillGroupByName(), your SkillGroup object includes the id. Your SkillDetail object doesn't. You're just creating it right there and then which means it hasn't been persisted to the database and doesn't have an id yet. Without an id, this error will come up. If you persist your SkillDetail object first then your SkillCollection object you should be fine.

```
SkillDetail skillDetail = SkillDetail.builder()
            .name("Advisceren")
            .build();

skillDetailRepo.save(skillDetail); //this is what you need to add

SkillCollection skillCollection = SkillCollection.builder()
            .skillGroups(skillGroup)
            .skillDetails(skillDetail)
            .build();

skillCollectionRepo.save(skillCollection); //then this will work
```

Comment: I just went to try your solution and I got an "java-cannot-find-symbol-error: Builder()" error...
Crazy how you let your code rest for one day, and you see problems happening.

Comment: That didn't solve it, i still have the same issue.

Comment: Then the problem may not be specifically in the code that you shared. Just checking in. Did you ever find the fix?

Comment: No not yet, I think the problem is because that the detached entity problem happens when you try to save an entity without a primary key.

So my guess would be that I have an entity whose primary key is not generated automatically, and I am not setting them properly prior to saving.